# Installing old kernel 3.4.69 in Linux 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, kernel, realtime

Can I possibly install a kernel 3.4.69 in place of the kernel 4.15? I have tried to do it for 3.4.4 and have been unsuccessful. What can I do? I really need 3.4.69 for Etherlab 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not due to the requirements of some of the supporting libraries and utilities are distributed together and there are some dependencies.  Thus if you really really want to do this, you might but with a bit of effort and probably a lot of instability and problems.

How about trying to find an older version of Ubuntu containing the kernel release you want.  This would be more stable however it would not have any real support however.  But in doing what you are suggesting you would not have that anyway.